# How to sync/update an out-of-sync replica?

Tags: arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase, replication

We have ArcSDE replicas (both one-way and two-way) of our databases between a number of different servers/locations, and have found that some of the feature classes are out-of-sync even though the replicas have completed successfully.  As a result there are more features in one FC than in its replica, and potentially also attribute values that are also different.

You can see in this screenshot there are 39 more records in one than in the other:
[image]

I have tried to manually run the sync (no-change) and also attempted to copy the missing features manually, which resulted in the new copies being replicated (and duplicated) so I had to remove them again.

How can I get my two feature classes back in sync without messing about with features as described above, and without having to recreate the child replica?  Is this even possible?

Windows Server 2012 R2
SQL Server 2012
ArcGIS for Server (SDE) 10.3
ArcGIS for Desktop 10.3.1

Comment: I had something similar happen once when features were added outside of an edit session. This was back around arcgis-10 I think. My memory is a bit hazy but I think the solution I found was to make a copy of the extra features, then delete the features outside of an edit session, I might have even used straight SQL. Finally I pasted them back in from within an edit session. This was in a 2 way replica, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Dowlers thanks for your comment - editing out the extra features will be the last resort solution if a better one isn't found, but I am hoping for a solution to force the sync

Comment: Are the 39 features still in the a table of the feature class?

Comment: @Dowlers I've checked a couple of the records - they are in the A table

Comment: Have you tried making another edit to them so they are put back in a state that will be synced? Also to state the obvious, the edits weren't made in a child version were they?

Comment: Made the comment into an answer with a bit more of an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a minor edit each of the 39 features. This should update their StateID value in the A table to a state that hasn't been synced with the other replica. When you next sync they should be picked up as an add and synced to the other replica

Comment: I made some a minor edits and then re-synced and I'm back to completely matched replicas! Thanks

Comment: Seems so simple when you know how!

Comment: Glad it worked. I'm curious as to how it happened in the first place. I work with replicas a lot and have never seen it happen before, now I'm worried it's happened in the past to my own replicas and I never noticed ;(

Comment: Unsure how it happened, but I have my suspicions.  We have a new app (built in-house) that modifies the replica feature classes (among other things) and think a bug or two may have caused issues.  The edit dates for the 39 records in question were from a month ago so am assuming at this stage that there were no more replica issues since then.  I'm watching closely now to be sure.